expanding $\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$ in terms of $\frac{1}{x}$ terms
Is there a way to write $\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$ as a series in $\frac{1}{x}$. For example, for large values of $x$ (meaning far from $0$) is it correct to say
$$\cos{\frac{1}{x}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2! x^2} + \frac{1}{4! x^4} + \ldots  $$

Well, yes, and for small values of $x$ as well. More generally, if $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jt^j$ converges to $f(t)$ for all $t\in S$, then $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(g(t))^j$ converges to $f(g(t))$ for all $t\in g^{-1}[S]$.

This is related to Laurent series.

The radius of convergence for $\cos()$ is infinite $||<\infty$ then the radius of convergence for $\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ should be the annulus $||>0$. Here is the proof: $\cos()$ is convergent in $||<$ for any $>0$ then if $z=\frac{1}{x}$ $\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is convergent in $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<$ i.e. $||>\frac{1}{}$. Simply take the limit as $→∞$

Yes, since the Maclaurin series for cosine is
$$
\cos u = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}u^2 + \frac{1}{4!}u^4 
- \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}u^{2n} + \cdots
$$
we can substitute $u = \dfrac{1}{x}$ to obtain
$$
\cos \frac{1}{x} = 1 - \frac{1}{2!\,x^2} + \frac{1}{4!\,x^4} 
- \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!\,x^{2n}} + \cdots
$$
And for a fixed finite number of terms, just as the Taylor polynomial becomes a better approximation as $u \to 0$, the center of the expansion, in the reciprocal variable, we have a better approximation as $x \to \pm \infty$.
